# ¿ Por qué manda NullPointerException al tratar de actualizar un campo en Java SpringBoot?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, nullpointerexception

Tengo el siguiente código, lo que quiero es actualizar la tabla **CONTROL**, solo en el campo **CLAVE_ESTADO** por medio del **ID**

tengo el siguiente query

```
    @Repository
    public interface ControlRepository extends JpaRepository<ControlEntity, String> {
    
      @Transactional
      @Modifying
      @Query(value = "UPDATE CONTROL C SET CLAVE_ESTADO=?1 WHERE C.ID=?2", nativeQuery = true)
      ControlEntity updatebyId(String cveEstado, String id);
    
    
    }
```

El servieImpl

```
@Service
public class ControlServiceImpl implements ControlService {



@Autowired
private ControlRepository repository;

@Override
public ControlEntity actualizar(String cveEstado, String id) {
    
    return repository.updatebyId(cveEstado,id);
}


}
```

y el método en el Controller

```
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    private ControlEntity actualizar(@PathVariable("cveEstado") String cveEstado,
            @PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return controlService.actualizar(cveEstado, id);
    }
```

al correr la app manda el error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'controlController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'controlService'; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'controlServiceImpl': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'executionControlRepository' defined in
> com.repository.ExecutionControlRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException:
> Could not create query for public abstract com.model.ControlEntity
> com.repository.ControlRepository.updatebyId(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
> Reason: null; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null     at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.QueryUtils.createCountQueryFor(QueryUtils.java:607)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]

Answer (score 1):

Esta es la solución que encontre, la cual funciona correctamente:

Cambie el tipo de dato de la propiedad Id a un tipo de dato númerico por lo que en el controller, service y repository también efectue el cambio

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

Controller: Aquí faltaba en los parámetros requeridos por el path el cveEstado

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
@Autowired
ControlService controlService;

@PutMapping("/{cveEstado}/{id}")
private void actualizar(@PathVariable("cveEstado") String 
cveEstado,@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
     controlService.actualizar(cveEstado, id);
      
}
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public interface ControlService {

public void actualizar(String cveEstado, Long id); }


@Service
public class ControlServiceImpl implements ControlService {

@Autowired
private ControlRepository repository;

@Override
public void actualizar(String cveEstado, Long id) {

 repository.updatebyId(cveEstado,id);
}
}
```

Respository: Aquí solo modifique el método a tipo void ademas del tipo de dato del id como mencione antes

```
@Repository
public interface ControlRepository extends JpaRepository<ControlEntity, 
Long> {

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "UPDATE CONTROL C SET CLAVE_ESTADO=?1 WHERE C.ID=?2", 
nativeQuery = true)
void updatebyId(String cveEstado, Long id);
```

Comment: gracias, Tambien cambie la version del springboot, porque aun con estos cambios me mandaba nullpointer, pero ya quedó